# Frequency to volt conversion problems

Tags: frequency-measurement

[image]

Converting frequency to voltage using LM 331 is causing me problems.

- Frequency range: 0-200 Hz
- V.out ref: 3,5v at 100 Hz (3000 RPM)
- 5,0V at 150 Hz (4500 RPM)
- V.cc: 12v.

A sensor picks up the mpulse from a two point cam on a shaft to detect RPM. Rising RPM causes rising frequency.
via the LM331. Increasing frequency creates increasing voltage as it should, but suddenly at a certant level of voltage it drops down to a new level. From this level the voltage increases with the rising frequency again.

Example: Shaft starts a rising RPM from 0 to 4500, the voltage output from the LM331 follows linearly. At f.ex 80 Hz the voltage is 3 V. Increasing to 81 Hz voltage drops down to 1 V. From this level voltage rises linearly again up to the end at 4500 RPM / 150 Hz / 5 volt.

Why this drop down at 80Hz?

NB: I have tried to make this with LM2917, but it will not work at all with this inductive sensor.

Comment: We need to see the full schematic of the relevant part of the circuit.

Comment: We also very much need details on the sensor, itself. And perhaps even details on the mechanicals, such as can, etc.